# DBIx::Class resultset creating related data without the select

Tags: dbix-class, perl

I'm trying to do something akin to this:

```
$schema->resultset('Foo')->create({ Property => 1,
                                       Bar => { 
                                                Property => 'non-unique',
                                             },
                                      });
```

Where Bar is a belongs_to relation to another table, Bar, with an auto-incrementing primary key.

Problem is that behind the scenes, dbix is always doing a select and finding an existing row in Bar with Property = 'non-unique', and inserting that row's PK into Foo. What I'd like it to do instead is create a new row in Bar each time with a new auto-generated primary key.

Is there a way to tell DBIx not to search for a matching related row first, but to force it to always create the related row?

Answer (score 2):

[create_related()](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Relationship/Base.pm#create_related)  or new_reated() 
The latter creates the related object, the former creates the object and saves it in the DB.

So, given an Foo->Bar relationship called 'bars', more like:

```
 $foo = $schema->resultset('Foo')->create({ Property => 1 });
 $bardata = {Property => 'non-unique'};                            
 $foo->create_related('bars', $bardata);
```