# How do I create rows without refetching related objects?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have the opposite problem of [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659083/dbixclass-resultset-creating-related-data-without-the-select).

I have an application that used to use this pattern a lot:

```
$rs->create({ foo => 'bar',
              status => { label => 'Active' } });
```

Behind the scenes DBIC will perform a `SELECT` to find out if the corresponding status object needs to be created, or if one with the label "Active" exists. If it does exist, its ID will be used as the value for the FK in the object I'm creating.

The thing is, the status table is almost never going to change, and there are not very many statuses, so 99.99% of the time it's basically a wasted query to the DB. We thought of using ENUMs instead, but it's very early days for the application so we are bound to have a few new statuses pop up in the first few weeks. INSERT is less of a pain in the *** than `ALTER TABLE status CHANGE label label ENUM(...)`. Plus having them in a table means we can list the possible values easily for the UI to build dropdowns.

So now we have a bunch of `get_THING_id` functions, that take a `THING` label and return an ID. The `get_THING_id` functions are [memoized](https://metacpan.org/pod/Memoize) and we do this:

```
$rs->create({ foo => 'bar',
              status_id => get_status_id('Active') });
```

It doesn't feel very DBIC-y and it's awkward having to import those all over the place.

Should we bite the bullet and just use ENUMs? What do people do for this type of tiny table?

Comment: Is it possible to pass a Result object as `status` with the syntax from the first code block?

Comment: @simbabque I don't have one, so it'd mean keeping a map like `"Active" => $active_status` around, which is basically memoization again.

Answer (score 1):

We have a ::Constants class (package) in our DBIC schema which containts constants for all those static things.
As it usually requires to adapt the schema or even application logic if the contents of such tables change, adding/changing the constants isn't an issue.

Comment: So you wouldn't use a separate `status` table at all, just constants? I can see the advantages but does that mean there is no FK constraint on your field, so you can put random values in there?

Comment: We do have that table to enforce the valid values using a constraint.